# Choose file name from its last name visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

How do we choose file from directory that contains specific last name based on date?

For example :

Flowdata20170504000000.csv (04-05-2017 00:00:00)

Flowdata20170503120000.csv (03-05-2017 12:00:00)

I want to choose flow data that contains date only today and yesterday from the current time?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question correctly, but this returns the paths of all the files containing today's and yesterday's date/time. Replace "mmddss" with "000000" or "1200000" if your querying that specific times.

```
Directory.GetFiles("Folder name").ToList().FindAll(File => { return (Path.GetFileName(File).Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyMMddhhmmddss")) || Path.GetFileName(File).Contains(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyMMddhhmmddss"))); });
```

Comment: If you want to return all files from yesterday and today, amend the above code to `.Contains(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyMMdd"))` & `.Contains(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyMMdd"))`

Comment: @SonthaHerdiawanAlvaro make sure you imported System.IO.